# Use arbitrary, dynamic HTML for $mdDialog contents

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material, mddialog

I want to be able to render and display any HTML (even containing javascript), coming from my server, in a dialog popup.

I am using a bunch of different combinations of `$compile(...html from server)($scope)` and `angular.element` and I cannot get it to work.

[Here is a codepen with some examples](https://codepen.io/5678-/pen/ExWeaWe).

The second and third buttons fail to produce a dialog as an error is thrown in the angular code.

What am I doing wrong?

Ideally the solution would allow for something like this

```
...
contentElement: some_func(... some HTML text from the server)
...
```

Comment: template literals are only for text.

Comment: @charlietfl "only for text" do you mean "strings"? The first button is an example of passing a string to `template:`. Otherwise I don't know what your comment is suggesting...

Comment: `popup_html(content)` in the codepen is using a template literal ``${content}`` but content is html

Comment: @charlietfl OK, but am I not passing a string for `content` every time in the codepen?

Comment: Yeah I might have overthought it a bit. That Pen is really broken so I didn't stay long

Comment: @charlietfl ah that would explain the misunderstanding. I just clicked the link myself and was presented with a broken pen (which is working in the tab I created it in). But if I made an edit, the output rendered properly.